# Spring-Boot : Referencing another Spring Boot Project

Tags: spring-boot

I created two spring boot projects, one is with JPA and the other with Web. I initially combined both of them into one project and everything works perfectly.

I now want to separate the JPA portion from the Web. So I added the JPA project as a dependency of the Web. But spring-boot is unable to detect the beans on JPA.

Is there any examples on how to implement this?

I am getting the exception when I tried to autowire the beans from the JPA project.

```
 BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details. How are you configuring your application? Are you using `@ComponentScan`? Did you rename any packages when you split the project into multiple JARs?

Comment: Hi @PhilWebb, just think I have a standalone boot project that has JPA (cruds) and some service classes. Then the other project has web functions i.e. Controllers. As mentioned when combined it's working fine. When separated, JPA works fine also. Further, without referencing the JPA project, the Web works fine on its own also. The problem, is when I autowire the dao from the JPA project to the WEB project. So to simplify the question, when you have two stand-alone boot project, and you decide you can use the functions of one, and decide to make it a dependency to the other. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, it actually works as is, I just have to made the package the same instead of renaming the web project to package.web.

Answer (score 0):

The `@EntityScan` and `@EnableRestRepository` by default only scan the sub packages of the current project so if you want to have two projects you should implicitly set the path of the other project to be scanned.